# Brightness Issue, Lenovo, Fedora 33

Tags: fedora, brightness

I'm having the brightness issue, where screen brightness doesn't change, on a Lenovo Legion Y740 with Fedora 33 that I haven't been able to solve yet.

Here's the output of `lspci | grep VGA`:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU106BM [GeForce RTX 2070 Mobile / Max-Q] (rev a1)
```

It defaults to the Intel graphics card.

Here's what my `/etc/default/grub` file looks like:

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="$(sed 's, release .*$,,g' /etc/system-release)"
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU=true
GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT="console"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="rd.driver.blacklist=nouveau modprobe.blacklist=nouveau nvidia-drm.modeset=1 rhgb quiet acpi_backlight=video rd.driver.blacklist=nouveau modprobe.blacklist=nouveau nvidia-drm.modeset=1 intel.modeset=1"
GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"
GRUB_ENABLE_BLSCFG=true
```

Here's some information that may be helpful.

I tried the suggestion the modify the `grub` file to change the `acpi_backlight` option. Before, the keyboard brightness keys didn't work at all. After changing to `video`, `Fn` + `F6` or `Fn` + `F7` make the window pop up that shows the bar for decreasing/increasing brightness, and the values change in the appropriate `brightness` file. However, brightness still does not change, this only turns the backlight off when I set brightness to 0.

I've also installed `xbacklight`, which doesn't work. I haven't debugged this yet, but when running `xbacklight -dec 10`, I get `No outputs have backlight property`, but I don't think this is the main issue.

I think the following two paragraphs may be indicative of the main issue.

When I find the file that holds the numerical value for brightness, in my case, this is `/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness/` when the Intel card is active, and I modify the value in place, the brightness doesn't change unless set to 0.

Next, on install I noticed that there are settings for `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/` for the keyboard, in the file `00-keyboard.conf`, but no settings for the backlight. What's the file I should put here? Is there any package I can install that would put the proper config file here?

I've installed appropriate `intel` and `nvidia` drivers.

Does any one have any idea what might be the issue?

Thank you in advance for any links, suggestions, or consideration.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem on a Lenovo Legion 5 15ARH05H. Two suggestions:

- enter BIOS and enable switchable graphics (as opposed to discrete graphics). This solved the problem for me *but* from then on, I could not use a second screen via HDMI anymore, thus not an option.
- use `xrandr` as seen on [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62249/how-do-you-change-brightness-color-and-sharpness-from-command-line).
  Determine your screen as follows:

```
$ xrandr --current
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
   1920x1080    144.10*+
```

In my case, my screen is `DP-2` and I can change its brightness using `xrandr --output DP-2 --brightness` followed by a number between 0 and 1.
Two drawbacks of this method:

- the brightness keys are still not working
- it does not work in combination with `Night Light` (reducing blue tones in the evening and during the night), or at least not that I am aware of.